# seaborn not coloring bars in barplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, bar-chart, visualization

I have started working on my thesis and I already have a problem.
I am trying to do a bar plot of ca. 250 bars, but it seems like that seaborn is not showing colors for most of the bars. I thought it could cycle through the palette - but it just shows them white. If I take a smaller sample (up to 99 I think), every bar is colored.
Even having one single color (not a palette), shows white bars.

Here is the code and the graph:

[image]

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think that this problem arises because, by default in `seaborn`, the bars in a `barplot` are outlined with a thin white boundary line. When the bars themselves are very thin this white boundary is the only thing that you see. Try changing the plot command to:

```
g = sb.barplot(x = x, y = y, palette = sb.color_palette("RdBu", n_colors=7), lw=0.)
```

The `lw=0.` removes the boundary line and you should then see the bar colours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code to test the palettes of seaborn:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

print("Seaborn version : {0}".format(sb.__version__))
# Seaborn version : 0.10.0

print("Matplotlib version : {0}".format(matplotlib.__version__))
# Matplotlib version : 3.1.3
```

Just to let you know it worked with these versions

```
# simple color test without palette
n = 1000
x = np.arange(1,n+1,1)
y = np.random.randint(-100,100,n)*np.random.random(n)
sb.barplot(x,y)
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# with your color choices
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
sb.barplot(x,y, palette=sb.color_palette("RdBu",n_colors=7))
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

So it seems to work with the arrays of my code.

Maybe:

- Your data is not understood by seaborn (check you dataframe?)
- You have a bugged version of seaborn or matplotlib (try pip install seaborn==0.10.0 and pip install matplotlib==3.1.3)
- You can try another palette of color

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I think I understood your problem. It cames from this style, just comment/uncomment to see the result

```
# sb.set_style("darkgrid")
```

Sadly, I did not find any kwargs option related to the darkgrid style to remove the bug... So I propose we recreate this style manually!

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_facecolor('whitesmoke')
# background color
ax.grid(color='white', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
# the grid
sb.barplot(x,y,zorder=2, palette=sb.color_palette("RdBu",n_colors=7))
#zorder=2 to draw above the grid
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To reproduce OP's case use `sns.set_style("darkgrid")`.

Comment: I tried to update the two libraries but that doesn't solve the problem. Might it be my dataset? here is a shot of it. 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zswKN.png

The graphs only takes the first row and all the columns except the last one. I don't see why there would be a problem, to be honest.

(the color palette doesn't matter that much, but thank you a lot for that piece of code!)

Comment: Did you try to remove the "style" line sb.set_style(...)? Maybe my edit is not clear; with this line all the bars are white. The style might override some properties like the bar colors.

Comment: I did! Even just keeping sb.barplot(x,y) they are white.

Comment: Ouch! We can eventually bypass seaborn and reconstruct the graph with fancy matplotlib if you're interested?

Comment: @EnricaArchetti how did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sns.reset_orig()` before plotting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).